# Angular2 http POST body sent as null

Tags: angular

For POST request my server expects something like following:

```
{
  "contextId": 0,
  "role": "Test",
  "eng_reason": "string",
  "aspiration": "string",
  "perception": "string",
  "hobbies": [
    {
      "hobbyId": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "selected": true,
      "contextId": 0
    }
  ],
  "interests": [
    {
      "interestId": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "selected": true,
      "contextId": 0
    }
  ],
  "skills": [
    {
      "skillId": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "selected": true,
      "contextId": 0
    }
  ],
  "connections": [

  ]
}
```

My service has following function:

```
  createContext(context: ContextlModel): Observable<ContextlModel[]>{

    let body=JSON.stringify(context)
    console.log(body)

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'Context', {body} , options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

`console.log(body)` prints:

`{"contextId":0,"role":"Manager","eng_reason":"Manager","aspiration":"Test","perception":"Test","hobbies":[{"hobbyId":0,"name":"Sport","selected":true,"contextId":0},{"hobbyId":0,"name":"Reading","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"hobbyId":0,"name":"Music","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"hobbyId":0,"name":"Travelling","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"hobbyId":0,"name":"Movies","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"hobbyId":0,"name":"Cooking","selected":false,"contextId":0}],"interests":[{"interestId":0,"name":"Robotics","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"interestId":0,"name":"Designs","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"interestId":0,"name":"Web development","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"interestId":0,"name":"Mobile development","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"interestId":0,"name":"Agile","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"interestId":0,"name":"DevOps","selected":false,"contextId":0}],"skills":[{"skillId":0,"name":"Leadership","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"skillId":0,"name":"Adaptability","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"skillId":0,"name":"Communication","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"skillId":0,"name":"Time management","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"skillId":0,"name":"Critical thinking","selected":false,"contextId":0},{"skillId":0,"name":"Negotiating & persuading","selected":false,"contextId":0}],"connections":[]}`

However the response I get is as following:

```
[
  {
    "contextId": 11,
    "role": null,
    "eng_reason": null,
    "aspiration": null,
    "perception": null,
    "hobbies": [],
    "interests": [],
    "skills": [],
    "connections": []
  }
]
```

Everything is basically null. Why is it so? Why it does not set my body correctly even after JSON.stringify()?

**UPDATE:**

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
```

If I copy this console.log(body) and POST it through my Swagger API, it is successful, which means there is some problem in my Angular POST request.

Comment: What does the method on your server do with this request? Is it working properly there? Are you sure that result of that method is OK before you return it to the client? And what does `extractData` method do?

Comment: Yes, If I make the same request from Swagger it is successful. I will update my question with extractData()

Comment: Have you tried `let body = res.json() as ContextModel[];`? Or `let body = <ContextModel[]>res.json()`?

Comment: If I am not wrong, I guess you mean in extractData()?  But the problem is POST itself is not posting data correctly to my backend.

Comment: Yes, I meant `extractData`, it extracts JSON object from your response, you probably just need to cast that JSON object to `ContextModel[]`. If you want to see if you get the right data from the server, do `console.log(body);` in your `extractData` method.

Comment: Okay, no I did GET in my swagger API and there I can already see that data is not saved properly i.e. the response as I have shown. extractData() works correctly I suppose

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood your problem. Is the problem that you are not getting the input data correctly on the server side or that you don't get the correct response from the server to the client?

Comment: Yes the first case, POST request do not post data correctly, role, eng_reason etc everything is being sent as null although in console.log I see it.

Comment: Is it possible that  brackets around `body` are not needed? Try this: `return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'Context', body , options)`. Also, you could try it out without `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I tried that, but then POST fails saying media type not supported

Comment: without JSON.stringify() if I send {context} instaed of {body}, it's still the same

Comment: What if you just send `context` instead of `{context}`? `this.http.post(this.base_url + 'Context', context , options)`

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes that did work! Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. I added an answer that you can accept so people know that you don't need help anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Angular will take care of turning your object into JSON before sending it. You just need to provide the object you want to send:

```
  createContext(context: ContextlModel): Observable<ContextlModel[]>{
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'Context', context, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

PS--I often find it useful to use Chrome's Dev Tools Network tab to the exact contents of the POST from the browser's perspective. It helps me in debugging problems like this.